# Does the DriveApp.searchFiles function have a limit on the number of queries it can accept?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

When I have 87 or more queries (like [`title contains "sugar"`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters)) conjoined by the `or` operator, it fails with an `invalid q` error where the q is the query for the function [DriveApp.searchFiles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)). Nothing unusual happens when I use the same function on each query separately under a loop.

I have no clue as to what may be causing the error.

Comment: When I had checked the maximum characters of the search query of ``DriveApp.searchFiles()`` before, it was 29,925 bytes. But in your situation, I thought that this limitation might not be the direct reason of your issue. So can you provide the whole search query you are using? If the personal information is included, please modify them.

Comment: Add the textual error message and a [mcve]